# out-process COM registered failed

Tags: com

I developed a out process COM server, test.exe.
I ran `test.exe /regserver` to register my COM server.It worked for several days.
I did not change any code, and now I ran `test.exe /regserver`, the classes could not write to Registry anymore.There is no any errors popped up when I run the command.

Comment: Could you get any logs from Windows Event logs?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what type of Event log it belongs to. Administrative Event?

Comment: Yes, Just try windows logs ->Application (or) windows logs->System

Comment: There are many error like this The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{6B3B8D23-FA8D-40B9-8DBD-B950333E2C52}
 and APPID 
{4839DDB7-58C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0D7D}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.   But the clsid is not my class id.

Comment: Did you register the server with administrative privileges?

Comment: Of course.It ever worked.

Comment: Thanks, guys. There must be some problems with my Registry or some settings of my computer.I tried to run it on other computers, it works.So I don't think it is a good idea for me to focus on this problem of my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the route cause.
There was a "-" in my file path,so the words after "-" were treated as parameter,such as `-regserver`. After I put my exe in other directory whose path does not contain a "_", it worked.

Comment: I run my COM exe as administrator, it works. I think my default  administrator user still has less permissions than "Run as administrator".